# Need to get Yesterday, MTD and YTD as a column in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have few column like product, loanid, sanction_amount and sanction_date.
I want to build dashboard in below format.

|  | Yesterday_sanction_date | MTD | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product | Count_LoanID AvgSanctionAmt | Count_LoanID AvgSanctionAmt | Count_LoanID AvgSanctionAmt |
| ------- | ------ | ------ | --- | ----- |
| ABC |  |  |  |
| XYZ |  |  |  |
| AHA |  |  |  |

Just to confirm that the Count_LoanID and AvgSanctionAmt are different column under Yester_sanction_date, MTD and YTD.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AR5A.png)

Comment: Can you please explain refine your question I am not really sure I understood what you try to achieve and what the problem is you're facing

Comment: Dear @st.huber , i am looking for yesterday's , mtd and yts's count of loanID and avg_sanction_amount... this is like product wise.. that is column 1 (Product)